# SQL query to retrieve data from 2 tables

Tags: sql

can you help me with something rather easy that my head just can't solve

I have 2 tables:

- table 1 = movies
- table 2 = actors

Let's say I have 3 movies: Independence Day, Reservoir Dogs and Forrest Gump.

I also have 7 actors: Will Smith, Jeff Goldblum, Quentin Tarantino, Michael Madsen, Tim Roth, Tom Hanks, Robin Wright Penn.

Let's say I want to run a query that will bring me the right movie where Will Smith and Jeff Goldblum appear. How should the query look like?

This should be really easy but I feel very dumb now..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your schema look like? Do you have foreign keys?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: You need to share your table schema. And try to Google sql joins before sharing that.

Comment: Dave Zych is right, we need to see your database structure.

Comment: I don't have foreign keys... Kind of a noob and not sure of what the concept of the foregn keys is.. :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use a table that matches `Actors` up with `Movies`. Call it `AppearsIn` and have two columns `MovieId` and `ActorId` that correspond a movie with a particular actor. What you're trying to produce is called a "Many-to-Many" relationship, you should look into that more for examples on how to produce queries and schemas for this data set.

Comment: Interesting... I will look for a tutorial to explain me this. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To set up a movies/actors relationship, you'll need three tables instead of two.

```
**Movies**
Id, Title

**Actors**
Id, Name

**MovieActors**
MovieId
ActorId
```

You can query movies by actor with the following:

```
select m.* from movies m
inner join MovieActors ma on ma.MovieId = m.Id
inner join Actors a on a.Id = ma.ActorId
where (a.Name = 'Will Smith' OR a.Name = 'Jeff Goldblum')
```

Just change the where clause to get different movies based on actor. Make sure you don't expose yourself to sql injection also.

Good luck!

Comment: 1000 Internets for you sir! Have a great Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

Say you have three tables: [Movies], [Actors] and [AppearsIn]. The latter matches movies to actors.

```
Table [Movies] columns:
[MovieId] (uniqueidentifier, primary key)
[MovieTitle] (varchar)
...

Table [Actors] columns:
[ActorId] (uniqueidentifier, primary key)
[ActorName] (varchar)
...

Table [AppearsIn] columns:
[AppearsIn_ActorId] (uniqueidentifier, foreign key on [Actors].[ActorId])
[AppearsIn_MovieId] (uniqueidentifier, foreign key on [Movies].[MovieId])
```

Then:

```
SELECT [MovieTitle] FROM [Movies]
INNER JOIN [AppearsIn] ON [AppearsIn].[AppearsIn_MovieId] = [Movies].[MovieId]
INNER JOIN [Actors] ON [Actors].[ActorId] = [AppearsIn].[AppearsIn_ActorId]
WHERE [Actors].[ActorsName] IN ('Will Smith', 'Jeff Goldblum')
```